# The Binary Version Of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected Version is 1.6.0 build error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I'm developing an Android app with flutter and Dart, but everytime I try to run the app, or build It, It returns me the same erro:

```
e: /home/ju-bei/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

e: /home/ju-bei/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

e: /home/ju-bei/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.8.22/1a8e3601703ae14bb58757ea6b2d8e8e5935a586/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

I'm trying to solve this problem, but anything I try, don't help.

If os needed more information, I update the post here.

OS: Ubuntu Linux
Device: Android 28 API

I've changed the build.gradle, app/build.gradle and settings.gradle, but the erro continues